# For the linguists among us: I like loud singing vs I like singing loudly

Tags: meaning, parts-of-speech, syntactic-analysis, noun-phrases, gerund-phrases

Can you explain why using "loud" as either an adjective or an adverb changes the meaning of the sentence. Is it just an English convention, or is there something deeper going on?

I like loud singing = I like turning the volume up on my stereo

I like singing loudly = I break wine glasses when I sing in the shower

Comment: Great question! I don't see a logic for it.

Comment: Because the gerund case is just another verb with the same subject as the main one, but the adjective is not a verb so there is no subject expressed.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/479169 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/66 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/346877 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/388099 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/428552 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/435916 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/428044 
 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/154886 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/366906 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/13860 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/148670  https://english.stackexchange.com/q/358212

Comment: Isn’t this a duplicate of [Does a ver­bal noun turn back into a verb when mod­iﬁed by an ad­verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/479165/2085)?

Comment: @tchrist I don't think so. My question is semantic. I want to know if there is a grammatical/ linguistic reason why the meaning of the sentence changes so drastically. I only looked at three of them though. I'll look at more to make sure.

Comment: 'I like loudly singing' would still mean me doing the singing. The word order actually has more effect than the adjective/adverb difference.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I think I figured it out. :-)

> I like singing loudly

Singing is a verb, and as we know, an adverb (loudly) modifies a verb.

> I like loud singing

Singing is a gerund (verb functioning as a noun), modified by the adjective, *loud*.

And there's the kernel of your answer:

> I like walking.
>
> I like dancing.

Etc., these are things that **I** like doing. Here's another example of the same phenomenon. Compare:

> I like guitar playing.
>
> I like playing guitar.

...**playing** as a verb vs. **playing** as a gerund.

Comment: Gerunds are verbs so they can take com­ple­ments and ad­verbs as in *play­ing gui­tar loudly*. But when you have a de­ver­bal noun, it can no longer take those things; in­stead as a mere noun it now takes ar­ti­cles, ad­jec­tives, and at­tribu­tive nouns the way you have with *good gui­tar play­ing*, where *play­ing* is a de­ver­bal noun (not a gerund!) mod­i­ﬁed by the noun *gui­tar* used at­tribu­tively.

Comment: @tchrist I want to understand you but you are a pretty technical in your explanations. Are you saying that singing or playing are not both gerunds in the two situations described, but one is called a gerund and one is called a deverbal noun (which I am unfamiliar with). Am I right?

Comment: @Johnny Thanks for your answer. I thought both situations involved gerunds so I'm going to wait on tchrist to shed some light on this. Said another way, how can modifiers change the grammar of the word they are modifying?

Comment: @JosephO. Yes, I am. In modern analysis, we distinguish words whose form is that of the *-ing*  inflection of a verb according to their function. If they accept complements and adverbs, then they’re still verbs no matter whether the entire phrase is used as a nominative phrase or as a modifier phrase. When they lose their verbness, they become deverbal nouns or deverbal adjectives. When you have a lone word without any words around it, it can be ambiguous whether it’s still a verb in all its glory or whether has been unverbed into a mere noun or adjective. There may be some adverbs, too, IIRC.

Comment: @tchrist So if I start with "I like singing", you are saying 1) this is ambiguous because "singing" could either be a gerund or deverbal. 2) It becomes one or the other depending on whether I modify it with an adjective in which case it now moves nominal and becomes a deverbal OR if I modify it with an adverb, it moves toward verbness and becomes a gerund. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @JosephO. That’s about right. John Lawler has postings about this somewhere here.